# gradle: failure when plugin task `dependsOn` another plugin task

Tags: gradle, gretty

testing gradle as replacement for maven, we have a build.gradle file that contains the following plugins

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.6"
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: "com.moowork.grunt"
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
```

`./gradlew appStart` and `./gradlew grunt_dev` run fine from the console.

However when adding the line

`appStart.dependsOn grunt_dev`

to the script, `./gradlew appStart` fails with

`Could not find property 'appStart' on root project 'blah'.`

Why is the `appStart` task visible from the gradle wrapper and not inside the script ?

Documentation on [gretty appStart](https://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/appStart-task.html)

**UPDATE**

Following @Opal explanation below, the following allowed hooking the tasks together

```
//Tasks defined in plugins are added after all projects are evaluated
//We have to hook after the evaluation to prevent an evaluation failure
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.appStart.dependsOn grunt_dev
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the following piece of code is added to `build.gradle`:

`project.tasks.each { println it.name }`

it can be seen that `appStart` is not in the list. Why? Probably the task isn't created at the moment of applying `'org.akhikhl.gretty'` (build script evaluation) but later on, during runtime.

Will try to check that in a moment.

**EDIT**

And [here](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/d6fb3be583a9de01b28052bc23b18249e5966877/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/GrettyPlugin.groovy)'s the explanation. Tasks defined in gretty plugin are added after all projects are evaluated (read about gradle's lifecycle). This piece of code (at the very end of `GrettyPlugin.groovy` is responsible for such behavior:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
  addRepositories(project)
  addDependencies(project)
  addTasks(project)
  afterAfterEvaluate(project)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. That would be a good explanation since `gradle tasks` however, does return `appStart`.

Comment: Yes, `gradle tasks` command returns `appStart`. But it's on the list while processing the `build.gradle` script. Add the code I provided at the end of script, then run just `gradle` and investigate the output.

Comment: OK. makes sense. I will investigate how I can make the `dependsOn` happen anyway; I guess by hooking to an `afterEvaluate` event if that exists

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. Find task in afterEvaluate and define dependency.